# Equivalent Card Combinations for n-Cards

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I'm hoping to develop a formulaic approach to answering a problem to do with dealing card games. I will be using the output of this formula as a checksum against an algorithm that I made. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

**Parameters & Background**

- We represent equivalent card combinations (hereafter, archetypes) by notating them or their component groups as suited ('s', sharing a suit) or offsuit ('o', not sharing a suit). For instance, AKs might be A-clubs K-clubs or A-diamonds K-diamonds.
- In a two-card game, there are 1326 unique combinations ((52 x 51) / 2) that reduce to 169 archetypes. [This grid](https://www.splitsuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Poker-Range-Matrix.png) shows an arrangement of two-card archetypes: Pairs run down the diagonal. The top-right hands are suited, bottom left are unsuited. The density of combinations represented by each archetype is variable. There are 12 offsuit combos, 6 pair combos, and 4 suited combos for each respective element.
- Develop a formula or algorithm that returns the number of archetypes for n-cards. For instance, in a 5-card archetype, we may see notation like AKs74s3o indicating that the A-K share a suit, 7-4 share another, and the 3 is a different suit altogether.

Is there a formulaic way to arrive at the archetype count without brute-forcing it?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Can we say two sets of cards have the same archetype if and only if they're related by a permutation of the suits?

Comment: Does the offsuit notation only apply to single cards, and do permutations of suit sets count as different types? For example, 1o2o versus 1s2o versus 2s1o versus 2o1o.

Comment: You say : 1326 that reduce to 169 archetypes ; are you sure 169 is correct ? Can you explain how you obtain 169 ?

Comment: Great questions, everyone. Here's some answers:

@aschepler: Yes, that sounds like a good heuristic. That rule should allow for combinations like AcTc5c (clubs) to be equivalent by permutating the suits to AdTd5d, both of which are of the archetype AT5s.

Comment: @JunoKim Offsuit notation applies to single cards that are not of the same suit as any others in the archetype, and to multiple cards that are both offsuit to each other _and_ to the other cards in the archetype. So, AT5o is an archetype where each card is a different suit. ATs5o is a suited combo with an offsuit dangler. ATsK5o is a suited combo with two cards that are offsuit to both each other and the suited combo.

Comment: @Lourrran Sure thing. We can represent these archetypes on a 13x13 grid, like the one in this image [link](https://www.splitsuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Poker-Range-Matrix.png). Pairs run down the diagonal. The top-right hands are suited, bottom left are unsuited.

The density of combinations represented by each archetype is variable. There are 16 offsuit combos, 6 pair combos, and 4 suited combos for each respective element.

This grid offers an exhaustive view and simplifies all 1326 two-card hands into (13x13 = 169) archetypes.

Comment: Ok. I did not understood correctly the concept or archetype. I think you should add the link to the image in the original question to clarify.

Comment: @Lourrran Good idea. I've done so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer , too long for comment.

1st point, error in your count, There are 12 offsuit combos, not 16. You can check that total should be 1326.

With 3 cards, if you want to check your process, My result is :

AcKdQh and similar : 286

AcAdKh and similar : 156

AcAdAh and similar : 13

AcKcQd and similar : 858

AcAdKd and similar : 156

AcKcQc and similar : 286

Total 1755.

If you also find 1755, we can consider we are both correct. If not, maybe I am wrong, maybe you are wrong.

There is no formula valid for any number of cards ; if you want to check more, you need to focus on some values.

example, 5 cards, AcAdKcKdQh and similar : 858.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the combo count in my description.

So, my understanding with what you've put forward here is there is no simple formulaic way to do this. The solution will always be algorithmic, and will involve counting the number of unique combos per each subtype/archetype. 

Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Same process as in my answer. It is not really algorithmic. When we choose a 'meta-archetype' (for example AcAdKcKdQh), the formula to obtain 858 is 13*12*11/2 ; this formula is mathematic, not algorithmic. The catalog of all meta-archetype is complex.

Comment: True, but if I am understanding correctly we need to iterate through the combos algorithmically in order to get the size of the entire set of archetypes for n-cards, correct?

Comment: The word combo is not clear. In your original message, you say : There are 12 offsuit combos, 6 pair combos, and 4 suited combos for each respective element. 12 , 6 and 4 can be found by algorithm, and also by mathematic. 858 in my previous comment can be found by algorithm or by mathematic. So if you need to check your algorithm, you can use some mathématic. In my answer (with all detail), 858 ... 286, it is mathematic ; 1755 is mathematic, not algorithm. Same result for 6 or 7 or any number of cards can be done with mathematic, but it is long and complex.